# Simplification of Expected momentum

Tags: fourier-transform

I am having trouble simplifying an equation that describes expected momentum of a wave function. The problem asks us to express expected momentum $〈\space  p \space 〉$ in simplified terms.

$$(1)\space\space\space\space\space\space\space\space\space\space\space\space〈\space  p \space 〉 =\int_{-\infty}^\infty \phi\dot(x)\space \hbar\space (-i)\frac{\delta}{\delta x}\phi(x)\space\delta x$$

where $\phi\dot(x)$ is the complex conjugate of $\phi(x)$

By definition of the fourier transform

$$(2)\space\space\space\space\space\space\space\space\space\space\space\space\phi(x) = \frac{1}{\sqrt{2\pi}}\int_{-\infty}^{\infty} \hat \phi(k) \space e^{ikx} \delta k $$

By substituting the fourier transform in for each $\phi(x)$ and $\phi\dot(x)$ we obtain

$$(3)\space\space\space\space\space\space\space\space\space\space\space\space〈\space  p \space 〉 =\int_{-\infty}^\infty \frac{1}{2\pi}\Bigg(\int_{-\infty}^{\infty} \hat \phi(j) \space e^{ijx} \delta j\Bigg)\space\space \hbar\space (-i)\frac{\delta}{\delta x}\Bigg(\int_{-\infty}^{\infty} \hat \phi(k) \space e^{ikx} \delta k\Bigg)\delta x$$

This is correct according to the solution guide. I don't understand why the complex conjugate form of $\hat\phi\dot(j)$ is not preserved. Instead the solution shows $\hat\phi(j)$.

The problem goes on to simplify further
$$(4)\space\space\space\space\space\space\space\space\space\space\space\space〈\space  p \space 〉 =\int_{-\infty}^\infty \frac{1}{2\pi}\Bigg(\int_{-\infty}^{\infty} \hat \phi\dot(j) \space e^{-ijx} \delta j\Bigg)\space\space \Bigg(\int_{-\infty}^{\infty} \frac{\delta}{\delta x} \hbar\space (-i)\space \hat \phi(k) \space e^{ikx} \delta k\Bigg)\delta x$$

Equation 4 brings in $\frac\delta{\delta x} i\hbar$ within the integral and brings back the complex conjugate form $\hat \phi \dot(j)$.
Notice there is a negative coefficient on the superscript of $e^{-ijx}$

There must be a principle of mathematics that I am unaware of. What happened to the complex conjugate form of $\phi\dot(x)$ and what brings it back after making the coefficient of the superscript negative?

Comment: Are you sure there isn't a dot on the parentheses around the first of the fourier transforms like $\dot{(\dots)}$. Also the derivative is with respect to x, the limits of the integral are constant (in the sense that infinity isn't a variable) so you are allowed to move the derivative inside the integral...and finally $(wz)^*=(w^*z^*)$ where I use star for complex conjugation

Answer (score 0):

Most likely, it is a typing mistake. Take the complex conjugate of the LHS and RHS of (2) to get $\dot{\phi(x)}$. Equation (4) shows the correct integral representaiton. But I am not sure why $\sqrt{2\pi}$ instead of $2\pi$ is appearing in (3) and (4).

Comment: Yes. One $\sqrt{2\pi}$ has been omitted. I've edited the original question to include it.

Comment: Is the fourier transform for complex conjugate waveforms $$\phi\dot(x) = \frac{1}{\sqrt{2\pi}}\int_{-\infty}^{\infty} \hat \phi\dot(k) \space e^{-ifx} \delta k$$?

Comment: First, I believe $f \rightarrow k$ in the integrand. Second, there is a difference between the Fourier transform of $\dot{\hat{\phi}{(k)}}$ and the complex conjugate of $\phi(x)$. In particular, $\dot{\phi}(x)$ is NOT the Fourier transform of $\dot{\hat{\phi}{(k)}}$.

Comment: Yes. $f$ is $k$. There is a negative exponent in the intergrand. Is that normal when taking the Fourier transform of a complex conjugate?

Comment: @Jeremy There are a couple of things that need clarifications. First, the Fourier transform of a signal $x(t)$, denoted by $X(w)$, is defined as $$X(w) = \int_{-\infty}^{\infty} {x(t) e^{-i w t}} dt.$$ If $X(w) = \mathcal{F}(x(t))$ then $\dot{X}(w) \neq \mathcal{F}(\dot{x}(t))$. In particular, $\mathcal{F}(\dot{x}(t)) = \dot{X}(-w)$. Third,

Comment: Third, $$\dot{X}(w) = \int_{-\infty}^{\infty} \dot{x}(t) e^{+i w t} dt.$$ Note that I have used $\dot{(ab)}=\dot{a}\dot{b}$. For more information on Fourier transform, check http://fourier.eng.hmc.edu/e101/lectures/handout3/node2.html

Comment: Fourth, sometimes, a scaling factor of $\frac{1}{\sqrt{2\pi}}$ is also used to define the Fourier transform. Fifth, the inverse Fourier transform is defined as $$x(t) = \frac{1}{2\pi} \int_{-\infty}^{\infty} X(w) e^{+i w t} dw.$$  Note that the scaling factor here is $\frac{1}{2\pi}$ when the scaling factor in $\mathcal{F}(\cdot)$ is 1. If the scaling factor of $\mathcal{F}(\cdot)$ were $\frac{1}{\sqrt{2 \pi}}$, the scaling factor in the definition of inverse Fourier transform would also be $\frac{1}{\sqrt{2\pi}}$.

Comment: Last, it seems that $\phi(x)$ as defined in (2) is the inverse Fourier transform of $\hat{\phi}(k)$. Again $f \rightarrow k$ in (2).

Comment: Thanks. I did not apply the property of complex conjugates
$$\dot{(a b)} = (\dot a\dot b )$$

Comment: This moves the complex conjugate into the itegral

$$\phi\dot(x) = \frac{1}{\sqrt{2\pi}}\int_{-\infty}^{\infty} \dot{\Biggr(\hat \phi(k) \space e^{ifx} \delta k\Biggr)}$$

Applying the property of complex conjugates

$$\phi\dot(x) = \frac{1}{\sqrt{2\pi}}\int_{-\infty}^{\infty} \dot{\Biggr(\hat \phi(k) \Biggr)}\space\dot{\Biggr( e^{ifx} \delta k\Biggr)}$$


This simplifies to

\phi\dot(x) = \frac{1}{\sqrt{2\pi}}\int_{-\infty}^{\infty} \hat \phi\dot(k) \space e^{-ifx} \delta k

The negative exponent is introduced in taking the complex conjugate of $e^ifx$

Comment: This simplifies to

$$\phi\dot(x) = \frac{1}{\sqrt{2\pi}}\int_{-\infty}^{\infty} \hat \phi\dot(k) \space e^{-ifx} \delta k$$

The negative exponent is introduced in taking the complex conjugate of $e^{ifx}$

Comment: I'm glad that you have figured out that we are just compute the complex conjugate of $\phi(x)$ and applying the property of complex conjugation.

Comment: Also

$$f \rightarrow k$$